# How to replace the string with arraylist elements using java

Tags: java

I have a string and arraylist elements.

For example :

```
String mystring = handbagging
ArrayList a = [ing, bag,and];
```

I want to replace the String with the arraylist elements and have it be `"h+and+bag+g+ing"`

Please suggest any ideas. thanks in advance...

Comment: Please write some code and post it here in case of any issues.

Comment: are u clear with your own question ? add some code ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question. You can use a `StringBuilder` to build a String from multiple Strings like this:

```
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s : myListWithString) {
      builder.append(s);
    }
   String resultString = builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to do here. But for a head start I am going to share with you a sample code which will give you the output you referred. 

 **Note:** this is not an optimized solution.

 This will not work if there are duplicate strings

 I just tried to give you an algorithm, you can come up with your own solution as you know actually what you want.

 do not do these string operations, use stringBuffer or StringBuilder

```
String mystring = "handbagging";
        ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
        a.add("ing");
        a.add("bag");
        a.add("and");
        System.out.println(mystring);
        for (Iterator<String> iterator = a.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            String string = iterator.next();
            if(mystring.contains(string)){
                int index = mystring.indexOf(string);
                mystring = mystring.substring(0, index) + "+" + string + "+" + mystring.substring(index + string.length());
            }
        }

        if(mystring.endsWith("+")){
            mystring = mystring.substring(0, mystring.length() - 1);
        }
        while(mystring.contains("++")){
            mystring = mystring.replace("++", "+");
        }
        System.out.println( "---" + mystring);
```